# read name and password from a file in c

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read name and password from a file into a structure in c, but clearly my code does not work as expected. Is there anyone can help me to figure out the problem with the codes attached below? Thanks a lot!
(Basically the file has several names and passwords, and I want to read them into a structure accounts[]`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct account {
    char *id; 
    char *password;
};

static struct account accounts[10];

void read_file(struct account accounts[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i=0;   // count how many lines are in the file
    int c;
    fp=fopen("name_pass.txt", "r");
    while(!feof(fp)) {
        c=fgetc(fp);
        if(c=='\n')
            ++i;
    }
    int j=0;
    // read each line and put into accounts
    while(j!=i-1) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s %s", accounts[j].id, accounts[j].password);
        ++j;
    }
}

int main()
{
    read_file(accounts);
    // check if it works or not
    printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n",
        accounts[0].id, accounts[0].password,
        accounts[1].id, accounts[1].password);
    return 0;
}
```

and the name_pass.txt file is a simple file like this (name+password):

hello    1234

lol    123

world    123

Comment: Could you explain how the code doesn't work?  Does it crash?  Does it hang?  Do you get unexpected output?

Comment: You should return the number of accounts read from your function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading file two times. So you need to [**fseek(), or rewind()**](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/fseek.html) to first char before second loop starts.

try with:

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // same as rewind()
```

or

```
rewind(fp);             // s
```

this code you need to add between two loops *(after first and before second loop)*

Additionally, you are to allocate memory for `id, password filed` in `account struct`:

```
struct account {
    char *id; 
    char *password;
};
```

or do allocate memory statically as @Adrián López suggested in his answer.

**EDIT**  I corrected you code:

```
struct account {
    char id[20]; 
    char password[20];
};
static struct account accounts[10];
void read_file(struct account accounts[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i=0;   // count how many lines are in the file
    int c;
    fp=fopen("name_pass.txt", "r");
    while(!feof(fp)) {
        c=fgetc(fp);
        if(c=='\n')
            ++i;
    }
    int j=0;
    rewind(fp);  // Line I added
        // read each line and put into accounts
    while(j!=i-1) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s %s", accounts[j].id, accounts[j].password);
        ++j;
    }
}
int main()
{
    read_file(accounts);
    // check if it works or not
    printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n",
        accounts[0].id, accounts[0].password,
        accounts[1].id, accounts[1].password);
    return 0;
}
```

and its working as follows:

```
:~$ cat name_pass.txt 
hello 1234

lol 123

world 123
:~$ ./a.out 
hello, 1234, lol, 123
```

Comment: but i don't know, but accounts[1].id and accounts[2].id are the same?

Comment: @Hello_World you are reading file twice. after first loop the file pointer points to a last char to you are to rewind you file pointer such that it point to first char. Read the link I given in my answer. Also you are reading in unallocated memory that is undefined behaviour. To resolve it first allocate memory. read what *Adrián López* suggested for one simple solution.

Comment: @Hello_World let me know if still you have problem.

Comment: Not just unallocated memory, but uninitialized pointers. It's kinda lucky that the file is first read, because no reading happens on the second pass and therefore no segmentation faults and some such ;-) I think, Helo_World, you need to do some reading first on the subject of working with files and memory allocations. And debugging techniques, like printing things out as you go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `malloc()` the content of the pointers in your struct or declaring then with an static size:

```
struct account {
    char id[20]; 
    char password[20];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably first allocate memory for the stuff you're `scanf`ing in. Keyword is `malloc`, a bit too long to lecture right here.